# image placement within a div with css

Tags: css, image, html

For a site I'm making I have to create the following block.

[image]

I have the following CSS that creates a white box with rounded edges and a shadow when used with the HTML below.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .stripeblock {
        width: 310px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    }
</style>

<div class="stripeblock">
    <h1>Just some title</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to...</p>
</div>
```

The only thing missing is the green horizontal stripe, I tried a couple of things but can't get it in properly.
I would like it to be included via the CSS and not be a seperate element within the div.
Is this possible?

Comment: Does `h1` have to be `h1`? I know it sounds weird, but if you used `inline` element you could make a `border-top`, of course only if the width of the green element can be as long as your title (not fixed)

Comment: No, the green element is fixed (115 x 5)

Comment: You could add image background to the H1 or do you not want to use images and pure html+css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely do this, without any extra images or markup.

Just use the ':before' pseudo element to style a block and place it where it needs to be.

Try this:

```
.stripeblock:before {
    background: #c8d300;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 7px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 20px;
    width: 125px;   
}
```

And make sure you add `position: relative;` to your `.stribeblock` to the `:before;` block is positioned correctly.

```
.stribeblock {
    position: relative;
}
```

Check out the results, here: http://jsfiddle.net/qVFeT/

Comment: Right on the money! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, do it with a background image

```
.stripeblock {
    width: 310px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    /*background-color: #fff;*/
    background:#fff url('some-rectangular-green-image.gif') no-repeat 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```